# Does Django hit the database when I access an object's attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does the following code query the database every time I call question.name?

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    test=models.ForeignKey(Test)

questions = Question.objects.filter(test=some_test)
for question in questions:
    question_name = question.name
```

My view takes a set of questions and user responses and scores a worksheet.  My goal is to execute all of the scoring without going back to the database, then save the result of my comparisons (a dictionary) using a background task where it's ok if it takes a little longer. I want to eliminate any unnecessary database hits.

Comment: This is a really good question by the way ! good job! should have generated more traffic in my opinion, hope I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is unclear but one thing for sure, at least one hit to the database will be required. Indeed, in your code sample your using:

```
question_name = question.name
```

But I don't see this working if `question` is not an instance of `Question` model beforehand.

So, considering your initial hit on the DB from a query to create an instance, `question_name` can then be reused as often as you want without having to access the database. See, this as a static instance of a row of your database.

**EDIT**

Now for your edit, it is not the same behavior. To correctly understand what happens behind the scenes, you need to understand the concept of "Laziness". In fact, since querysets are lazy in Django, this line:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(test=some_test)
```

won't result in any hit on the database. Querysets stands for sets of SQL queries. So, at this point, since you did not ask to fetch something from the database it is not actually evaluated yet. This is the wanted behavior because it makes sure the database is accessed only when it needs to. As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) says here are the cases where querysets are evaluated:

***Iteration***

> A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first
>   time you iterate over it.

***Slicing***

> Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated
>   QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the
>   “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a
>   QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.

***Pickling/Caching***

> repr(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call repr() on it. This is
>   for convenience in the Python interactive interpreter, so you can
>   immediately see your results when using the API interactively.
>
> len(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you
>   might expect, returns the length of the result list.
>
> list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it
>
> bool(). Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, such as using bool(),
>   or, and or an if statement will cause the query to be executed

So, as you can see situation 1 apply to your particular case. Iteration will result in hits on the database.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.  Does that make it a little more clear?  You did answer my question.  So calling `question.name` on an instance of `Question` won't be another database hit because the question that I've retrieved already has all the information from that row.

Comment: Well, you can try your above code but I doubt it will work since a queryset instance will be returned and it is not possible to iterate over it like you did. Is the code working like you posted?

Comment: I iterate over querysets like that all the time!

Comment: I missred your edit, I'm sorry. It is fine. But to answer your question, in this case it will hit the database everytime. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, this information is exactly what I was trying to figure out!

Comment: I hope it is right, someone decided to downvote whitout giving any insight. This is always sad because there may be a mistake in my explaination, but unfortunately I can't tell what it is. Anyway glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question, I've been searching for an answer too. From what I've read: The moment you start iterating over a `queryset`, all the rows matched by the `queryset` are fetched from the database and converted into Django models. This is called `evaluation` ([source](https://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/)).

Once a `queryset` is evaluated using any technique - either iteration or casting to `list/set` or using it in an `if` statement, and other techniques described [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-django-database-querysets-and-its-optimizations-1765cb9c36e5), iterating through it again or using its attributes will not trigger another query/database hit because it's cached already, unless -it's a foreign key attribute (forward or backward relationships fields) in which case you can use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to cache those as well so that accessing those will not result in a database hit ([source](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-django-database-querysets-and-its-optimizations-1765cb9c36e5)).

In short, once a `queryset` is evaluated, its attributes are retrieved and each object is cached and getting these with the dot operator will not cause a database hit because it's being retrieved from the cache and not database but if it's a foreign key attribute that you did not cache by definition say using the `cached_property` decorator or while retrieving the queryset using `select_related` or `prefetch_related`, accessing that attribute will cause a database hit ([partial source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes)).